# Hidden control seen as visible by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, visibility

I have a table as such:

```
<table class="RepaymentTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 200px;">

            </td>
            <td>
                %
            </td>
            <td class="y1">
                Year 1
            </td>
            <td class="y2">
                Year 2
            </td>
            <td class="y3">
                Year 3
            </td>
            <td class="y4">
                Year 4
            </td>
            <td class="y5">
                Year 5
            </td>
            <td class="y6">
                Year 6
            </td>
            <td>
                Total
            </td>
            <td>
                Return for creditors
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id="MainContent_lblNetMonthlyIncome">Net Monthly Income</span>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td class="y1">
                €<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtNetMonthlyIncomeY1" class="RepaymentValue" id="MainContent_txtNetMonthlyIncomeY1" style="width: 60px;" type="text" value="0.00">
            </td>
            <td class="y2">
                €<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtNetMonthlyIncomeY2" class="RepaymentValue" id="MainContent_txtNetMonthlyIncomeY2" style="width: 60px;" type="text" value="0.00">
            </td>
            <td class="y3">
                €<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtNetMonthlyIncomeY3" class="RepaymentValue" id="MainContent_txtNetMonthlyIncomeY3" style="width: 60px;" type="text" value="0.00">
            </td>
            <td class="y4">
                €<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtNetMonthlyIncomeY4" class="RepaymentValue" id="MainContent_txtNetMonthlyIncomeY4" style="width: 60px;" type="text" value="0.00">
            </td>
            <td class="y5">
                €<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtNetMonthlyIncomeY5" class="RepaymentValue" id="MainContent_txtNetMonthlyIncomeY5" style="width: 60px;" type="text" value="0.00">
            </td>
            <td class="y6">
                €<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtNetMonthlyIncomeY6" class="RepaymentValue" id="MainContent_txtNetMonthlyIncomeY6" style="width: 60px;" type="text" value="1000.00">
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="MainContent_lblNetMonthlyIncomeTotal">€  1000.00</span>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to calculate the total of the `input` fields in the row, but some columns are hidden using `$('y6').hide()`. I use the following jQuery to find each column and calculate the total:

```
var NetMonthlyIncomeTotal = 0;
$("input[id*='txtNetMonthlyIncomeY']").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() != "" && $(this).is(":visible"))
        NetMonthlyIncomeTotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
```

In ***[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2T2XM/)*** you can see that if you comment out the line `$('y6').hide()` then the total is 1000 (As `MainContent_txtNetMonthlyIncomeY6` value is 1000), but if you leave it uncommented the total is 0. This performs as I expect, however when running from my site, and not jsfiddle, `$(this).is(":visible")` always returns `true` and therefore the total is ALWAYS 1000.

Checking the DOM Explorer shows that `<td class="y6" style="display: none;">` correctly sets the `display` style, but in the debugger for the same page the `display` style isn't set and looks like `<td class="y6">`. I assume this is where the problem occurs.

Why would this happen? Visually the column is hidden, but it is still calculated. Is there a better way of finding whether the `input` control in the column is shown?

**EDIT:** The official api seems to suggest it works with display. http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was just a simple mistake by me. I was actually running the `$('.y6').hide()` code AFTER the calculation so when the calculation occurs it IS showing. Ensuring that the `hide()` call was before the calculation makes it work.

As mentioned in comments above, the `.is(':visible')` does check the `display` style as well as `opacity` and `visibility` and is therefore a valid use in this case. See ***[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ct5MN/)*** for examples of it's use.

**EDIT:** Although according to ***[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ct5MN/1/)*** the `.is(':visible')` function ONLY seems to work with the `display` style and not `visibility`/`opacity`...A new question might be required.

**EDIT 2:** In accordance with the [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) the above edit is correct:

> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible,
>   since they still consume space in the layout.

Therefore, as opposed to other answers, the ':visible' selector SPECIFICALLY checks the `display` style and `visibility: hidden` and `opacity: 0` will return true when used with the `.is(':visible')` method.

**EDIT 3:** This has been the case from Feb 2009 where we can see in the [release notes of jQuery 1.3.2](http://blog.jquery.com/2009/02/20/jquery-1-3-2-released/):

> This is how the logic has changed:  * In jQuery 1.3.1 (and older) an
>   element was visible if its CSS “display” was not “none”, its CSS
>   “visibility” was not “hidden”, and its type (if it was an input) was
>   not “hidden”.  * In jQuery 1.3.2 an element is visible if its
>   browser-reported offsetWidth or offsetHeight is greater than 0.
>
> What does this change mean? It means that if your element’s CSS
>   display is “none”, or any of its parent/ancestor element’s display is
>   “none”, or if the element’s width is 0 and the element’s height is 0
>   then an element will be reported as hidden.
>
> What is the benefit of making this switch? The result is two-fold:  *
>   The performance is much, much, better. (See below.)  * An element is
>   reported as “hidden” if it’s inside a “hidden” element (something that
>   wasn’t possible before, without the use of a plugin.

So this has been the case for a while.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery hide/show functions - are working with *display* style. and with *":visible"* selector you're look for *visibility* style.

Comment: Why does it work in jsfiddle though... The official api seems to suggest it works with display. http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/